# How does python variable assignment work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    n = numbers
    if len(n) > 0:
        n.remove (min(n))
    print (n)
    print (numbers)
    return n
```

Why are the n and numbers equal at the end, even though I change one and not the other?

Saw this on Codewars, but couldn't find an explanation on Google as everybody suggested

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: `n` is a reference to the same object as `numbers`, not a copy. (If you want to copy the list, the most readable way, provided that you are using Python 3, is to do `n = numbers.copy()` .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same reference object. You are updating a single instance of a  mutable list with two references.

To make two instances, at the expense of double the memory, you can copy the list

```
n = numbers[:]
```

Comment: I'm watching this answer receive 4 edits in real-time, and I wonder if it's standard SO practice to submit an incomplete answer and then flesh it out and what the reasons behind it could be.

Comment: You can see many people do that. Answer the question to get it there, then add more detail as necessary

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It shouldn't need to be that way, but based on a recent experience, the earlier that you get some kind of answer registered, the less likely you are to be subject to false accusations of plagiarism if someone else's answer has things in common with yours. I *don't* think people should post answers that are so incomplete as to be missing critical information, but there is nothing wrong with posting a valid answer even if there is more that could be said, and which you intend to add afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you did not realize is the `Referencing`. Now, when you do this `n = numbers`, the machine assigns the item's data to the variable `n` but also tells that, it is a referencing to the variable `number`.

Now, if any changes happens to `n`, that means it will reflect in `number` as well. You just need to assign it without referencing the item.